# JPA EclipseLink |getResultList returns always null

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Hi there for my Project for distributed application I need to implement something with JPA.

I set up the database and I can insert new Data to the database. My main problem is that I want to search data and get them to the dialogue (JavaFX)

My entity class is a extended one. Heres the Code:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Marines")
public class Marines extends Einheit
// Einheit = getter and setter Methods 
{
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String type; 
    private String punkte;
    private String modelSize;
    private String movement;
    private String closeCombat;
    private String rangedSkill;
    private String strength;
    private String conditions;
    private String wounds;
    private String armorValue;
    private String leadership;
    // Constructor (...) 
}
```

So my search call is with the id I want to search for the next entry in the dialoge with a buttonclick where id increments.

```
public List<Marines> showMarinesWithID(int id)
{
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("demo");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    String jpql = "SELECT m FROM Marines m WHERE m.id = 1";// + id;
    Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
    List<Marines> ma = query.getResultList();

    Marines foundMarine = em.find(Marines.class, 1);

    System.out.println(foundMarine.getName());
    return ma;
}
```

And there is already a problem: If I print it out it shows only null. As you can see I already tried the find method and a call with jpql. The value is always null. 
I have a search Method which works but there is an other case. There I just need the Name of the entries and display them. That looks like this:

```
public List<Marines> getMarineNames()
{
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("demo");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    String jpql = "select m.name from Marines m";

    Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);

    List<Marines> marines = query.getResultList();

    return marines;
}
```

Update 1: The SQL log from the first method

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-03-06 17:50:40.943--ServerSession(1404945014)--Connection(1537026053)--SELECT ID, ARMORVALUE, CLOSECOMBAT, CONDITIONS, LEADERSHIP, MODELSIZE, MOVEMENT, NAME, PUNKTE, RANGEDSKILL, STRENGTH, TYPE, WOUNDS FROM MARINES WHERE (ID = ?)
bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

Update 2: Screen of the database values: 
[Database entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePmlD.jpg)

Comment: why would you create an EMF in every method?! Create a single EMF and get an EntityManager when you need one. If wanting to DEBUG JPQL, look in the log at the SQL invoked, which gives the answer to your problem in most cases

Comment: In the second code sample the resulting list will not be of type `Marines` as you are selecting only the `name` attribute

Comment: If `System.out.println(foundMarine.getName());` prints null then you have found a marine but its name is null. Otherwise you would get a NullPointerException at this line!

Comment: @SvetlinZarev thank you for the information gonna change it to a String.

Comment: @NeilStockton just copied it from the book of the prof. But gonna change it. Thank you!

Comment: @911DidBush The names in the database are all filled. There is no null value with the id. Gonna upload pic in the next edit.

Comment: There is no need for a picture. What i wrote is just a fact: The entity manager find method would return null if no record was found and trying to call getName() on that would lead to a NPE. If you don't get an NullPointerException in the next line then `em.find(Marines.class, 1)` did return a result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Well simple as that: the entity class Marines needs the getter and setter. With the extension they cannot be used.